# neo4j import data slow for 50k dataset while creating relationship edges

Tags: neo4j

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UvKV.png)I have a hierarchical dataset node as shown in the image attached with the question. R1 has a specific id, R11,R12,R22,R21 have specific ids. However nodes All R2 and All R1 dont have dummy ids. Now i have a csv file storing the hierarchy details. I am trying to import the data and create the tree consisting close to 50k entries. However, its quite slow. The following is the query i am using to create:

```
using periodic commit LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///file.csv" AS row 
match (rTemp:Resource) where rTemp.id = toInteger(row.resourceSubid) 
match (r:Resource) where r.id = toInteger(row.resourceId)
merge (r)-[:has]->(allR) 
merge (allR)-[:has]-> (rTemp)
return r;
```

The time taken to create this hierarchy is too slow. How to over come this? 
Note: I have already created R1 and attached it to All R1/R2 nodes separately.

Comment: What is the `allR` in your query ? Do you have some constraints & indexes ?

Comment: It’s just a dummy node between the main resource and all d sub resources. Yes I have created d constraints and indexes

Comment: In your query `(allR)` is not defined, so it represent all the database nodes ... Basically you are linked all your database, this is normalthat such an operation is slow

Comment: allR is just a dummy node which connects to resources of one type ie if I have r11,r12 and so. Resources belonging to resource type 1, then allR will be used to connect to all d sub types.

Answer (score 0):

If you PROFILE or EXPLAIN your query, you'll note there's an Eager operation in the query plan.

Also, if you paste the query into the query textbox in the browser, you'll notice a warning which reads:

> The execution plan for this query contains the Eager operator, which forces all dependent data to be materialized in main memory before proceeding
>
> Using LOAD CSV with a large data set in a query where the execution plan contains the Eager operator could potentially consume a lot of memory and is likely to not perform well. See the Neo4j Manual entry on the Eager operator for more information and hints on how problems could be avoided.

Is `allR` necessary? If you remove the use of this variable and just use `merge (r)-[:has]->(rTemp)`, the eager disappears and the periodic commit will start working.

Also, is it necessary to `return r` at the end of the query?